# Phone randomly slowing

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

My phone is a Sony Xperia Z1s running lollipop, and I've noticed that this device loves to be very slow and choppy, even after a week after a clean install. The worst part, the slowing is inconsistent.  I have uninstalled Facebook, which seems to have helped, but not entirely. Are there any tips specific to my phone?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, Lollipop 5.0, 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 suffer by a RAM leakage which consistently slows down the phone, based on the number of times you lock the screen. If your warranty is void, or you don't care about voiding it, your best bet might be to migrate to a newer Android version.

Comment: I would love to do that, but I'm at the newest firmware provided by Sony for this phone.

Comment: You might want to enter the realm of custom firmwares, then, if one has been made to suit your particular model.

Comment: That is a possibility, but I would like to save that as a last resort thing. I just don't want to brick my phone. Could I use ADB to flash images to my phone like flashing images to an Nvidia shield, or is it a different kind of process? My phone comes with a companion software, do you think I could use that in case a custom firmware fails to install?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own a Sony device, so my guidance would be unreliable at best. I suggest you to wait for a Sony user, or to come asking in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts).

Comment: OK, so I used Clean Master lite, uninstalled some apps, and turned off animations in developer options. If I don't see that much improvement, I'll see if I can install a newer firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Does your phone have a cleaning system built in? If it does give this a try to see whether it makes a change. If not, maybe download an app such as Clean Master or something similar.

If worst comes to worst then you may have a virus. I recently had a problem with my computer graphics card where it suddenly became extremely slow. I found out later that I actually had a virus or malware installed without even knowing, which was affecting the graphics card's output (for whichever reason). Give malware-bytes or an anti-virus program of your choice to remove any possible issues you could have with the phone. If these don't work I'm afraid I can no longer help you :)

Comment: It's difficult that a phone has _that_ much junk after a week past the clean install. Plus, the majority of apps like Clean Master do just the opposite of what they claim. Don't let the fancy animations fool you.

Comment: I doubt I have a virus. Lookout comes pre installed on my phone and reports that my phone is clean. Besides, I don't install non-market packages that I don't already know are safe, like Amazon Underground, for example.

Comment: Yes, those cheat-sy "cleaning" apps do not always do what they intend; I know they sometimes just add more junk, rather than remove it. The only other guess comes in line with @DeathMaskSalesman and the comment they made on your original post; it could just be memory leaks. And I would also be surprised if you had a virus after a week, to be honest :)